# Raspberry Pi: No "Publish to cloud"?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, raspberry-pi

I'm running Mathematica 13.1 on a Raspberry Pi, and I want to publish my notebook to Wolfram Cloud. The [documentation tells me](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/FileMenu.html) to do this through the File menu, but the File menu I get (shown below) doesn't have a publish to cloud option. What am missing?

[image]